# Django: how to create a dynamic form from other models

Tags: django, forms, django-models, django-forms

I've got two models: Question and Survey

```
class Question(models.Model):
text = models.TextField()
category = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=(('personal', 'Personal'), ('team', 'Team'), ('company', 'Company')))
low_answer = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=True)
high_answer = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=True)


class Survey(models.Model):
description = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=True)
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
category = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=(('personal', 'Personal'), ('team', 'Team'), ('company', 'Company')))
questions = models.ManyToManyField(Question)
```

So, Survey has a field questions as ManytoMany, I now wonder how can I make a form on Survey that collects the answers of each Question? All I need for each question is a int value.
I do not want to build the form myself and I would much prefer to use django for this.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can build a form with multiple questions using [django models formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets)

On side note, I think you need `ForiegnKey` (`OneToMany`) relation from `Survey` to `Question` rather than `ManyToMany`. As a survey has many questions but a question instance is only in one survey.

Answer (score 0):

*** What do you need at first is a extra field in many-to-many relationships ***

In your models I miss a third class called `Answer`. An `Answer` is a response in a `Survey` for a `Question`. Your int value will be into this new class. See [Extra fields on many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) for more details. For your scenario:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    ...

class Survey(models.Model):
    ...
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(Question, through='Answer'))

class Answer(models.Model):                   #<- this is the new model
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey)
    response = models.IntegerField()
```

*** Now the formset ***

At this point, to build form, you can use [modelformset_factory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets)

```
from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory
AnswersFormSet = modelformset_factory(Answer)
formset = AnswersFormSet(queryset=Answer.objects.filter(question= some_question))
```

*** And that's all ***